# ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'user'@'localhost'

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to log into MySQL on a remote server. I have ssh-ed into the server, and I am trying to access the server's local MySQL db.

I got the login credentials from the config file of a local application

```
mysql -u user -p
```

but when I login using the same password, I get

```
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'user'@'localhost'
```

Details:

```
username: user
password: password
table   : table_name
host    : localhost
```

I have tried the same password a few times, but there must be something other than an incorrect password. I'm very confused, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Do you have sudo access ? Do you own or administer the server?

Comment: Every time this has happened to me it resolved to an incorrect password.

Comment: Cool. this just happened to me. I'll explain how I resolved it.

Comment: @csmu i have used the same password in the config

Comment: The only other thing I can think of is user may be a reserved word. Try using a different user name.

Comment: What makes you think that the access is granted to user@localhost? Do you have an application on that server using localhost? Are you *sure* it isn't connecting to the IP address of the local network interface (i.e. whatever `hostname()` resolves to?) If you have root access to MySQL, try `select User, Password, Host from mysql.user [where User='youruser'];` to see what logins are actually granted.

Comment: user what just an example, i dont want to write the real username

Comment: @lserni I have root to the site not to mysql, i have an application that is using that user and password to access the site's db

Comment: Just to check, try using the local interfaces' numeric IPs instead of localhost. You can get the list with the ifconfig command.

Comment: Also try 127.0.0.1 and ::1 . You never know.

Comment: You may want to try changing the application IP to 127.0.0.1 (after you have granted the appropriate privilege). Depending on various factors, connections through the loopback interface *might* show better performance (but it's *not* guaranteed and it might even make things worse; much depends on the actual network layer as well as application architecture). However, it's performance that would come for free, and well worth a try.

Answer (score 0):

1. get root privileges.

   sudo bash
2. stop mysql server -- ubuntu example

   service mysql stop
3. open mysql without checking passwords -- ubuntu example

   /usr/bin/mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables &
4. log in as root

   mysql --user=root mysql
5. Enable privileges

   flush privileges;
6. Change the password and grant any access you might need

   update user set Password=PASSWORD('password') WHERE User='username';

   GRANT ALL ON table_name.* TO 'username'@'localhost' ;

   flush privileges;

   exit ;
7. Exit safe mode and restart

   kill `cat /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid`

   service mysql start

Comment: i can stop the server, its on the live site

Comment: can you log in as root?

Comment: It's unclear to me why'd you have root access to the site but not to mysql. As @lserni mentioned ... you have to find out the actual permissions the user has from the mysql.user table. You probably have to add privileges for that user, and that means if you don't have the root access for mysql then you'll either have to find it or stop the server and set it.

Comment: You need to find out what access privileges the user has. You'll probably need to be able to change / update the privileges so you are going to need super user access .  The following question might help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10299148/mysql-error-1045-28000-access-denied-for-user-billlocalhost-using-passw?rq=1